# Trim method issue?

Tags: java, string, trim

So I am trying to validate a user input based on the length of a string.

```
String v=scan.next();
v=v.trim();
```

So if the input is "0 1 2 3" the resulting string is 0123 right? For some reason its returning the value of the first index and cutting off the rest and I don't know why.

Comment: Why do you think it should be `0123`?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `String.trim()`?

Comment: tim only removes whitespaces at beginning end end of a string. Not in the middle.

Comment: Please read the documentation, before asking questions, which are answered in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: @ARam You don't have to remember what every function do. However, you have to read the Javadoc of the functions you are using to understand what they are doing. The people at Oracle are doing a good job of documenting the core language methods, please make sure you make good use of that.

Answer (score 4):

> So if the input is "0 1 2 3" the resulting string is 0123 right?

The `trim()` method removes **leading** and **trailing** whitespace (meaning at the beginning and the end of the string), not the ones in the middle of the string.

If you want to remove all kind of whitespace (like space and tabs) **anywhere**, you should use:

```
v = v.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

(the + is not required, btw, but it performs differently than without. Prefer "\s" if you don't have many spaces in a row.)

If you only want to remove the space character, because you parse a very specific input, then use:

```
v = v.replace(" ", "");
```

> For some reason its returning the value of the first index and cutting off the rest and I don't know why.

Your problem lies in the fact that you use just `scan.next()` to get your input. It returns the next token, not the full line of user input. If you want the whole line, use the following instead:

```
String v = scan.nextLine()
```

Comment: This will still now work he needs to use nextLine and not next.